# A is a real and non-symmetric matrix of order 3. prove that the rank of the matrix $A-A^t$ is 2.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A is a real and non-symmetric matrix of order 3. prove that the rank of the matrix $A-A^t$ is 2.

We have $\rho(A)=\rho(A^t)$ where $\rho(A)$ is the rank of A.

Comment: Hint : tried to work with unknown entries : $A=\pmatrix{a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i} \rightarrow A - A^T = ?$

Comment: @JeanMarie All diagonals of $A-A^t$ becomes zero. But what can be said from it?

Comment: Compute its determinant.

Comment: Do you find $0$ ? If so the rank is $\leq 2$, do you agree ? And this is all that you can say, i.e., you will never be able to say that $rank=2$ (think to the null matrix).

Comment: @Jeanmarie Ok. I Understand. Is there no alternative approach using properties.

Comment: @JeanMarie the zero matrix is symmetric

Comment: @Bananach That's right !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

For any skew-symmetric (antisymmetric) real (in fact, over any field of characteristic$\;0\neq2$) matrix, we have that $\;\det A=(-1)^n\det A\;$ , so if $\;n\;$ is odd we get $\;\det A=0\;$

Further hint: in *your* case, the first two lines of $\;A-A^t\;$ are linearly independent provided $\;a_{12}\neq a_{21}\;$ . Generalize.

Comment: A is not skew-symmetric rather non-symmetric.

Comment: @user1942348 I know that. That is *not* what the hint is referring to.

Comment: I think the proof is like the following : $A-A^t$ is always skew-symmetric for all A. Then $\;\det  (A-A^t)=(-1)^n\det (A-A^t)\;$. Here $n=3$, so $\det (A-A^t)=0.$

Comment: @user1942348 Now you got it. Nice. Now just check that $\;\text{rank}\,A=2\;$ with the given data.

Answer (score 2):

Setting $A=\pmatrix{a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i} \ $, one has $\ B:=A-A^T=\pmatrix{0& b - d& c - g\\-b + d& 0& f - h\\-c + g& -f + h& 0}.$

The characteristic polynomial of $B$ is:

$$\tag{1}p(x)=- x\, (x^2 + \Delta)$$

where

$$\tag{2}\Delta:=b^2 + c^2 + f^2 + d^2 + g^2 + h^2 - 2\,b\,d  - 2\,c\,g  - 2\,f\,h$$

Letting $U=(b,c,f)$, $V=(d,g,h)$, we can write:

$$\tag{3}\Delta=\|U\|^2+\|V\|^2-2U.V=(U-V)^2 \ \ \text{in the sense of dot products}$$

But, as $A$ is assumed non symmetrical, $U\neq V$, thus $\Delta>0$.

Consequently, using (1), the spectrum of matrix $B$ is:

$$\{0, -i\sqrt{\Delta}, +i\sqrt{\Delta}\}$$

Therefore, as $\Delta>0$, the rank of $B$ is always exactly 2.

Remark: I recognize that, at first, I thought that other cases could be possible.

---

**Edit**: there is an interesting geometrical interpretation of the eigenvalues.

Let us denote, in order to have simpler notations,

$$B=\pmatrix{0& -\gamma & \beta \\ \gamma & 0& -\alpha \\-\beta& \alpha & 0} \ \ \text{and} \ \ X_0=\pmatrix{\alpha\\\beta\\\gamma}$$

Then, with :

$$X:=\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}, \ \ \text{on can check that} \ \ BX=X_0 \times X \ \ \text{(cross product)}$$

This explains that

- $BX_0= X_0 \times X_0 = 0$, i.e., $BX_0=0X_0$, proving that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ associated with eigenvector $X_0$.
- if $X_1$ is any vector in $X_0^{\perp}$ (the 2D plane orthogonal to $X_0$),
  $BX_0= X_0 \times X_1$, which, in particular is an element of $X_0^{\perp}$ which is orthogonal to $X_0$ : it amounts to a $\pi/2$ rotation in plane $X_0^{\perp}$, this rotation being in full correspondance with multiplication by a purely imaginary number.

Comment: I have added an edit.

Comment: The geometrical interpretation is indeed very insightful